# Unable to Restore Graph

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

**Problem**: 

Attempting to restore meta_graph via `tf.train.import_meta_graph("saved_models/model.meta")` gives the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape [-1] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: Placeholder_2 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

The shapes of placeholder and the data passed are as follows:
    placeholder: (?, ?, 50)
    data: (1, 2, 50)

---

**Code Involved**:

Placeholder involved: `self.x_placeholder_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, n_inputs])`

The other placeholder (label): `self.y_placeholder_label = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, self.num_of_classes])`

Predict method:

```
def predict(self):
    with tf.name_scope("predict"):
        with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("saved_models/model.meta")
            saver.restore(sess, "saved_models/model")

            graph = tf.get_default_graph()
            output = graph.get_tensor_by_name("optimize/cal_loss/model_network/model_network_NN_network/output/BiasAdd:0")
            x_placeholder = graph.get_tensor_by_name("Placeholder:0")
            print x_placeholder.shape
            print np.array(self.data_x).shape
            print sess.run(output, feed_dict={x_placeholder: self.data_x})
```

Train Method:

```
 def train(self):
        writer = writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("mygraph/logs", tf.get_default_graph())

        num_of_epoch = 10
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            for epoch in range(num_of_epoch):
                # initialise all variables
                optimize = self.optimize
                sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

                sess.run(optimize,
                         feed_dict={self.x_placeholder_input: np.array(self.data_x),
                                    self.y_placeholder_label: np.array(self.data_y),
                                    self.sq_placeholder_seq_length: np.array(self.seq_length)})

                if num_of_epoch % 10 == 0:
                    # Create Saver to save model
                    print "Cycle " + str(epoch) + " out of " + str(num_of_epoch) + " done"
                    saver = tf.train.Saver()
                    location = saver.save(sess, "saved_models/model")
                    print "Model saved to : " + str(location)
```

---

**Question**: Is the problem due to placeholder having ***two None*** when defining it's shape? It is fine when training though.

---

**Full Code (if it helps): **
(https://gist.github.com/duemaster/660208e6cd7856af2522c2efa67911da)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience you are getting this error because you are not feeding the value of that placeholder in the restored model. You'd normally expect to get the error "you must feed the value for placeholder XX" when you forget to feed it, but I've noticed that when placeholders have `None` in their shape vector (with restored models), the error would be the one you are getting about negative dimensions. I've got this error even with 1 `None` in the placeholder shape, and properly feeding its value solved the problem.

Comment: First time RNN user. Missed out the Seq_length placeholder.